# Specify table name mid application Ruby-Datamapper

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I'm wanting to dynamically create and query tables using Datamapper.

While Datamapper allows you to work with legacy tables and schemas, and in this way set the table name used this is only during initialisation, not within the application.

Is there an easy way to tell Datamapper to migrate/upgrade a Model with an assigned table name in application, and to then tell it to query this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way without changing anything under the hood is to use separate databases instead of tables (assuming that any relationships will also be stored in the separate database) and open a connection to an additional repository in the block.

```
DataMapper.setup(:external, "adapter://username:password@hostname/dbname")
DataMapper.repository(:external) do...end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem.

All Ruby classes can be created, and re-defined at run-time. Even initialization is at run-time. Initialization just happens to be executed first, before other code is executed.

That is why monkey-patches work so easily. It's just additional code at initialization that just re-defines classes to add extra methods, variables etc.

There is no Ruby code that is "special" in the sense that it only runs at compile time. Ruby is an **interpreted** language.

---

To dynamically create a class, see [Dynamically creating class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576827/dynamically-creating-class-in-ruby/576909#576909).

Assuming you don't need to dynamically create classes from an array of strings, you can define additional methods with `define_method`, or call Datamapper methods at runtime to add attributes.

To define new methods in a class:

```
Post.send :define_method, :new_method_name do
end
```

To define a new property using the Datamapper property:

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :title, String # the static way
end

Post.send :property, :title, String # add property the dynamic way (at run-time)
```

**Do note that any tables or properties you define at run-time will not be available if you restart your server, unless the code that dynamically generates these are re-executed.**

---

To update your tables at runtime, you simply do the same thing as normal, that is, call:

```
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

To upgrade only a single table, you can also do:

```
Post.auto_upgrade!
```

---

**2nd warning: If you have multiple processes, the dynamic code will need to be run in each process, or the additional table Models and Properties will not be available.**

This is a problem if you have multiple worker processes, as might happen in production (eg. Nginx with multiple Unicorn workers, or multiple Mongrel workers behind a Ha_proxy).

If you have a single process server, then that is not a problem. However, if you have multiple worker processes, you must run the dynamic code to generate these extra classes and properties in EACH process to make it available.

This is actually the same for initialization, because each process goes through initialization (or if forked, inherit any initialization).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add an answer! I guess I could simply change the legacy schema a DataMapper model uses and `auto_upgrade` when I needed to evaluate it, but was hoping there was an easier way of specifying this property at run time that avoided having to `auto_upgrade` or `auto_migrate` as I'd rather not do that in a production environment.