# Ruby Rails - Go through Array & Save Each Value As A Unique Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My array contains a varying amount of objects.  I need to iterate through the array and save each object `id` as a unique variable.  Given the amount of objects within the array will vary, how should I do this?

```
"items"=>[{"id"=>"B00668BTCI"}, {"id"=>"B0041KJSL2"}]
```

I need to save the information to a new object that can support up to 16 IDs.  @object.id_one, @object.id_two, etc...

Comment: Where do you want to save the information?

Comment: I need to save the information to a new object that can support up to 16 IDs.  object.id_one, object.id_two, etc...

Comment: Will the array contain entirely different objects (i.e. a mixture of strings, hashes, arrays, numbers) or only the length of the array will vary (i.e. 2 or 10 or 200 hash elements as shown above)?

Comment: Only the length of the array will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suitable way to save your data all depends upon how you want to reference it or access it later. Meta-programming is interesting and fun, but may be overkill depending upon your needs. You will need to determine that after looking at the choices. An alternative way is in an array:

```
array_of_ids = items.map(&:values).flatten
```

Or

```
array_of_ids = items.map { |item| item["id"] }
```

Then all of the IDs are in the array `array_of_ids` and becomes, in your example:

```
["B00668BTCI", "B0041KJSL2"]
```

Accessible by:

```
array_of_ids[0]  # first id
array_of_ids[1]  # second array
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some meta-programming here...
[Here is a post for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576827/dynamically-creating-class-in-ruby), it has an answer (by Chirantan) that shows how to create instance variables dynamically.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Just in case you get interested to learn more, I have also found a good article about creating methods dynamically, check it out.

[Dynamically adding class methods in Ruby by Ryan Angilly](http://ryanangilly.com/post/234897271/dynamically-adding-class-methods-in-ruby)